# Angular github pages path has duplicate app names

Tags: angular, github, github-pages, angular-tour-of-heroes

I tried to build and deploy angular-tou-of-heroes application to github, but always got duplicate app name in the path. Could anybody help me with this issue?

My build command is ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href angular-tour-of-heroes
I deployed from Github /doc directory. 
When click the link, it keep redirect to the flowing path, which has two tour-of-heroes in it
https://frankxiao008.github.io/angular-tour-of-heroes/angular-tour-of-heroes/

Here is my Github repository link for my code.
https://github.com/frankxiao008/angular-tour-of-heroes

I followed this instruction
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUPYK.png)

Comment: Why did you set your  `--base-href` to `angular-tour-of-heroes`?

Comment: I just follow the official instruction  https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 3):

I just pulled your project and tested it with a local server. I think there was a mistake in the documentation. If you set `--base-href` to an `x` value, your application will use `/x` as the based path. See the `base` [tag](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).

The solution is simple, let it have the default value by removing the option

```
ng build --prod --output-path docs
```

or set it to the current directory

```
ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href .
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, that would works. Then go to Github repository, in the setting menu, in the deploy branch selection, choose to deploy from master/docs branch. By this way, the URL for  the online website would be https://username.github.io/project name

Comment: Glad to help. Could you please upvote my answer btw?